# user verification email for registration page

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I am implementing a registration process on my site in vb.net.  I have written the sql that INSERT's the user details into my database including a random string as the Verification code.  An email is then sent to the user with a verification link.  The link has a query that is the verification code.  From the link, the user is directed to a page that has an on_load event that checks if the code from the query string is the same in the database.  Every time i test it the user is directed back to the Default page, meaning that the query string verification code was not the same as that in the database.  Please can someone tell me what is wrong with my code.  I suspect there is a few glaring errors but I am quite new to sql and so not sure why its not working.

**Code to add register input details to database and to email them the verification link (after database is updated with random string:**

```vb
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.Mail
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Class Account_Register
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Protected Sub RegisterWizard_FinishButtonClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.WizardNavigationEventArgs) Handles RegisterWizard.FinishButtonClick

        'ADD NEW USER ACCOUNT DETAILS TO USER DATABASE --------------------------------------------------
        Dim oPath As String = Server.MapPath("~/app_data/databaseX.mdb")

        Dim oReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Nothing
        Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing

        If Not agreeTerms.Checked Then
            agreeTerms.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red
            Return
        ElseIf Page.IsValid Then

            Dim Letters As New List(Of Integer)
            'add ASCII codes for numbers
            For i As Integer = 48 To 56
                Letters.Add(i)
            Next
            'lowercase letters
            For i As Integer = 97 To 122
                Letters.Add(i)
            Next
            'uppercase letters
            For i As Integer = 65 To 90
                Letters.Add(i)
            Next
            'select 8 random integers from number of items in Letters
            'then convert those random integers to characters and
            'add each to a string and display in Textbox
            Dim Rnd As New Random
            Dim SB As New System.Text.StringBuilder
            Dim Temp As Integer
            For count As Integer = 1 To 8
                Temp = Rnd.Next(0, Letters.Count)
                SB.Append(Chr(Letters(Temp)))
            Next

            Dim oUserId As Integer = 0
            Dim oName As String = txtName.Text
            Dim oUserName As String = txtUsername.Text
            Dim oPassword As String = txtpsswrd.Text
            Dim oActiveAcc As String = "Yes"
            Dim oVerCode As String = SB.ToString
            Dim oVerUser As String = "No"
            Dim ologged As String = "No"
            Dim oOrg As String = txtorganiz.Text
            Dim oTel As String = txttelephone.Text
            Dim oEmail As String = txtEmail.Text
            Dim oTown As String = Txttown.Text
            Dim oRegStart As String = Date.Today
            Dim oSubscribedUser As String = "No"

            oConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxxx", oPath))
            oConnection.Open()

            Dim ipAddress As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

            Dim oCommandSession As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Users ([Name], Username, [Password], ActiveAccount, VerificationCode, VerifiedUser, LoggedIn, Organisation, Telephone, email, Town, RegistryStart, SubscribedUser)" & _
            "VALUES (oName, oUserName, oPassword, oActiveAcc, oVerCode, oVerUser, ologged, oOrg, oTel, oEmail, oTown, oRegStart, oSubscribedUser)", oConnection)
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oName", oName))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oUserName", oUserName))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oPassword", oPassword))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oActiveAcc", oActiveAcc))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oVerCode", oVerCode))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oVerUSer", oVerUser))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@ologged", ologged))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oOrg", oOrg))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oTel", oTel))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oEmail", oEmail))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oTown", oTown))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oRegStart", oRegStart))
            oCommandSession.Parameters.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@oSubscribedUser", oSubscribedUser))
            oCommandSession.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If Not oConnection Is Nothing Then
                If oConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                    oConnection.Close()
                End If
            End If

            'SEND REGISTERATION CONFIRMATION EMAIL TO USER ------------------------------------
            Dim oReciever As String = txtEmail.Text
            Dim mm As New MailMessage("xxxxx@shippingresources.net", oReciever)

            mm.Subject = "Registeration complete : Shipping Resources.net"
            mm.Body = "<table align='center' width='70%' cellpadding='10' style='text-align: center; border: 3px solid #3366cc; background: #4576ea; color: #333'>" & _
            "<tr><td colspan='2' style='background: #3366cc'><img src='http://www.shippingresources.net/Imgs/TitleBanner.png' width='100%' /></td></tr>" & _
            "<tr><td colspan='2' style='text-align: left; text-indent: 50px'>Hello " & txtName.Text & ",</td></tr>" & _
            "<tr><td colspan='2' style='font-size: 28px; padding: 10px auto 10px auto'><b>You're nearly there.  You now just need to click the below link to verify your account</b></td></tr>" & _
            "<tr><td colspan='2'><a href='http://www.shippingresources.net/Account/VerifyAccount.aspx?id=oVerCode'>Verify account.</a></td></tr>" & _
            "<tr><td colspan='2' style='height: 80px'></td></tr>" & _
            "<tr><td colspan='2' style='background: #3366cc'>&copy; Shippingresources.net 2013 &nbsp;<img src='http://www.shippingresources.net/Imgs/logosmall.png' style='position: relative; top: 8px' /></td></tr>" & _
            "</table>"
            mm.IsBodyHtml = True
            Dim smtp As New SmtpClient()
            smtp.Host = "mail.shippingresources.net"
            smtp.EnableSsl = False
            Dim NetworkCred As New System.Net.NetworkCredential()
            NetworkCred.UserName = "xxxxxxxxx@shippingresources.net"
            NetworkCred.Password = "xxxxxxxxxx"
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = True
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred
            smtp.Send(mm)
            Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx")
        End If

    End Sub
End Class
```

**The code behind page VerifyAccount.aspx to check if te random code (oVerCode), is the same as in the database and update the database column "VerifiedUser" as "Yes":**

```vb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Partial Class VerAccount
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page


    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        Dim VerifyAccount As String = Request.QueryString("id")

        Dim oPath As String = Server.MapPath("app_data/databaseX.mdb")
        Dim oValid As Boolean = False

        Dim oReader As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = Nothing
        Dim oConnection As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection = Nothing

        Try
            oConnection = New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0}; Jet OLEDB:Database Password=xxxxxxxx", oPath))
            oConnection.Open()

            Dim ipAddress As String = Request.ServerVariables("REMOTE_ADDR")
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand

            Dim oParams As New List(Of System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter)
            oParams.Add(New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbParameter("@VerificationCode", VerifyAccount))

            Dim oCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
        "SELECT VerificationCode FROM Users " & _
        "WHERE VerificationCode = ?", _
        oConnection)
            oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", VerifyAccount)
            oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()

            If oReader.Read() Then
                oValid = True
                Dim oVerCode = oReader.GetString(oReader.GetOrdinal("VerificationCode"))
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
        Finally
            If Not oReader Is Nothing Then
                If Not oReader.IsClosed Then
                    oReader.Close()
                End If
                oReader = Nothing
            End If

        End Try

        If oValid Then
            Dim oUserVerified As String = "Yes"
            Dim oCommandSession As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
                    "UPDATE Users SET VerifiedUser = ? " & _
                    "WHERE VerificationCode = ?", _
                    oConnection)
            oCommandSession.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", oUserVerified)
            oCommandSession.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", VerifyAccount)
            oCommandSession.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/RegistrationComplete.aspx")
        Else
            Response.Redirect("~/Account/VerificationFailed.aspx")
        End If

        If Not oConnection Is Nothing Then
            If oConnection.State = Data.ConnectionState.Open Then
                oConnection.Close()
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Many thanks for any kind help :)

Comment: Are you sure the value of the oVerCode variable is in the email link?  It looks like you might have a string literal.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I think so unless I am misunderstnading you.  I am declaring as String and when it is generated it is saved to the database as a string.

Comment: I think @DanBracuk is on to something here. Your code that assigns a value to `mm.Body` does `VerifyAccount.aspx?id=oVerCode'`, not `VerifyAccount.aspx?id=" & oVerCode & "'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank both.  there were two issues, firstly i am very embarrassed to say the path to my
database was wrong.  Also as you both suggested the email link should have been:



`VerifyAccount.aspx?id=" & oVerCode & "'`

instead of a literal string.

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Full marks for using parameter queries. You just need to clean up your code a bit.

First, in Jet/ACE OLEDB the parameters are purely positional. We can give them names, but the names are ignored: All that matters is that the parameters are defined in the exact order in which they appear in the CommandText. Normally we just use `?` for the parameter placeholder.

So, in your first case, try

```vb
Dim oCommand As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
        "SELECT VerificationCode FROM Users " & _
        "WHERE VerificationCode = ?", _
        oConnection)
oCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", VerifyAccount)
oReader = oCommand.ExecuteReader()
```

[Side note: If `oReader.Read()` returns `True` then you don't need to retrieve the value from the OleDbDataReader because you already have it. (You just used it as the parameter to your WHERE clause.)]

Then, later on, use something like

```vb
Dim oUserVerified As String = "Yes"
Dim oCommandSession As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand( _
        "UPDATE Users SET VerifiedUser = ? " & _
        "WHERE VerificationCode = ?", _
        oConnection)
oCommandSession.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", oUserVerified)
oCommandSession.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", VerifyAccount)
oCommandSession.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Thanks Gord, sadly i still can't get my code to work and have been working for hours :(  Need to learn more SQL i think.  In an attempt to try and find out where my error(s) are, I am going to post all my code in the original question above. :)